# How to Install python's psycopg2 library in RHEL?

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, psycopg2, rhel

I am trying to install psycopg2 library in RHEL but i am getting an error

[image]

After looking at similar questions asked on site, I also tried to install psycopg2-binary first but it showing the same problem

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the development sources of postgresql

```
yum install libpq-devel
```